# Animating sine wave in js

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe, trigonometry

I'm trying to animate a sine wave in JS but it's not acting as expected. I'm using a `<canvas>` element along with `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method but it's a CPU hog and as i change frequency with the slider it just break and show random waveforms. I also don't know if drawing adjacent lines is the best way to represent a sine wave. Please note that i'll use vanilla JS and that the sine's frequency and amplitude are variables set by sliders. Thanks in advance.

This is what i got so far: http://cssdeck.com/labs/8cq5vclp

**UPDATE:** i worked on it and this is the new version: http://cssdeck.com/labs/sbfynjkr

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  cHeight = canvas.height,
  cWidth = canvas.width,
  frequency = document.querySelector("#f").value,
  amplitude = 80,
  x = 0,
  y = cHeight / 2,
  point_y = 0;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.querySelector("#f").addEventListener("input", function() {
    frequency = this.value;
    document.querySelector("#output_f").value = frequency;
  }, false);

  drawSine();
}

function drawSine() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineTo(cWidth, y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  for (x = 0; x < 600; x++) {
    point_y = amplitude * -Math.sin((frequency / 95.33) * x) + y;
    ctx.lineTo(x, point_y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  requestAnimationFrame(drawSine);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="f" type="range" min="0" max="20000" value="20" step="1">
<output for="f" id="output_f">20</output>
<canvas width="600px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: It looks blocky and broken because you are doing i*10 as your x co-ordinate. Remove the *10 and reduce the frequency by a few thousand fold and it is much smoother.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett i tried removing the *10 but it's still broken. The frequency range needs to be from 20 to 20k Hz as the sine represents a sound. I noticed that it draws the same, wrong, sines periodically: try 440 and 6710 (or 8000 and 17000) and you will get the ~same result.

Comment: What's happening is that because x is an integer value (i.e. a pixel) you will get patterns determined by the error from the real curve, try using (x*0.01) and see the values again, you can notice in this smaller sample of the curve the small errors that make the wave look 'bouncy' - if that is what you mean by broken. Or you could explain more what you expect. Perhaps look at Nyquist Frequency for a better explanation of discrete sampling.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett i searched a bit and i found that my problem is related to aliasing. Any way i can handle it? Also i discovered AnalyserNode and i think that could really solve the problem, but i didn't understand it fully.

Answer (score 3):

I've messed around with sine waves quite a bit, because I'm working on a little project that involves animated sine waves. I've got some code you might be interested in taking a look at. Like mentioned earlier, you need to make sure you are using the right increment in your loop so the lines do not look jagged.

https://jsfiddle.net/uawLvymc/

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
function(f) {
  return setTimeout(f, 1000 / 60)
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

function getPath(height) {
  var width = canvas.width;
  var spacing = 0.08;
  var loopNum = 0;
  var pointList = [];
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < width / 2; i++) {
    pointList[loopNum] = [loopNum, Math.sin(loopNum * spacing) * (i * height) + 100];
    loopNum++;
  }
  for (i = width / 2; i > 0; i--) {
     pointList[loopNum] = [loopNum, Math.sin(loopNum * spacing) * (i * height) + 100];
     loopNum++;
  }
  return pointList;
}

function draw() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var runTime = currentTime - startTime;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(80, 100, 230)";

  var height = Math.sin(runTime * 0.008) * 0.2;
  var pointList = getPath(height);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(pointList[0][0], pointList[0][1]);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(pointList[i][0], pointList[i][1]);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Sorry I didn't really edit down the code, it's just a direct copy from what I was working on. Hope it helps though.

Answer (score 2):

See if this example could help you a little

[Sine Wave Example canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/Aj2h4/1/)

```
    function init()
    {
        setInterval(OnDraw, 200);
    }

    var time = 0;
    var color = "#ff0000";

    function OnDraw()
    {
        time = time + 0.2;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var dataLine = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var value = document.getElementById("lineWidth");

        dataLine.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        dataLine.beginPath();

        for(cnt = -1; cnt <= canvas.width; cnt++)
        {
            dataLine.lineTo(cnt, canvas.height * 0.5 - (Math.random() * 2 + Math.cos(time + cnt * 0.05) * 20 ));
        }

        dataLine.lineWidth = value.value * 0.1;
        dataLine.strokeStyle = color;
        dataLine.stroke();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you need the Math.random() part in there, also the frequency can be changed by varying the 0.05 value and the amplitude with the 20 value as per OP's question

Comment: the random is to demo `noise` presentation. Remove it, you will get a clean sine wave.

Comment: @jhyap thank you for your input, but i need the sine to be "still", not moving.

Comment: @pinetreesarecool may I suggest removing 'animating' from the title then, this is what I thought you meant by 'animating' (moving).

Comment: @JordanTrudgett well that's still an animation because it must change when frequency or amplitude are changed...